# Is it possible to include a javascript function call into php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am stuck with this issue. I have a js function into a scripts.js file:

```js
var userLoggedIn;

function openPage(url) {
    if(url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        url = url + "?";
    }
    var encodedUrl = encodeURI(url + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn);
    $('#mainContent').load(encodedUrl);
}
```

I call the javascript function from a php file like this:

```js
<?php

//This file should check if the requested url is sended by AJAX or it's manaually typed by the user into the browser
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    include 'includes/config.php';
    include 'classes/Artist.php';
    include 'classes/Album.php';
    include 'classes/Song.php';

} else {
    include 'includes/header.php';
    include 'includes/footer.php';

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo "<script>openPage('$url')</script>";
    exit();
}

?>
```

It works fine when it's called from an onclick event into the HTML document, but it doesn't works when I enter manually the url. It prints a string into the screen. However this code is taken from some sample coding pages and it seems to work this way. What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance for the help and be patient... i'm a beginner on this!!

Comment: That script tag needs to be in the `<html>` document

Comment: Can you share more details? How is that PHP code "called form an onclick event"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have the mentioned above js code loaded somewhere. Do you have it loaded in header or footer? (Directly or by loading your `scripts.js`?)

Be sure to have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js">
```

Somewhere printed in your code. Do you have it in your footer or header?

Assuming that you have your js code in scripts.js now you can execute after page loads, but be sure print the `<script>` part WITHIN your `<html>...</html>`. So if you print out `</html>` in your `footer.php` then be sure to print:

```
echo "<script type="text/javascript">openPage('$url')</script>";
```

BEFORE loading of footer (but after loading of `scripts.js`);

While you learn a bit more you will get to know that actually it is a bad thing to execute code parts like that: you should separate your markup from code which executes things directly from it.

Modern frameworks will assist you with that, there is also `defer` attribute of the script element (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) which helps to execute the code after the page actually loads.

Comment: Ok, it's loaded into the header. The header and footer are present in every page. So, the function should change only the area of main content.

Answer (score 0):

So, after reviewing all the code i found the problem. There was a missing ">" in the html closing tab. Now it works!! Thank you for your help!